# SQL editor on IBM Infosphere Data Warehousing

Tags: sql, data-warehouse

Our Technical Team is migrating all database analysts over to *IBM Infosphere Data Warehousing*, we are currently using Eclipse with *SQL Explorer*.

I've been trialling the new system yesterday and find the SQL editor highly confusing. I could get used to *SQL Query Builder*, but it is restricted to just **ONE** SQL query. We normally do write very long SQL scripts with hundred's of single SQL queries.

The only alternative for multiple SQL queries is the SQL and *XQuery* editor. Once I've written the first query the content assist does not offer to include Schema's and Table's anymore. There is no way to copy paste it from the catalogue either, so do I really need to type all tablenames out in full every single time ???

Our Technical Team will not provide any training to us and already told us that we have to figure it out ourselves.

Comment: OK, the schemas and table names only show up once one has entered FROM. However, as soon as I start the second query all tablenames will be underlined as errors!

Comment: Also, If I run more than one script, I do not get any results windows, although the "SQL Results View Options" are set to "Multiple Windows". I do get a separate window for a single query, but for multiple ones I only get the execution notice and NOTHING else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend InfoSphere Data Studio or Infosphere Data Architect in your case. Both products facilitate development of SQL queries and stored procedures.

Comment: I thinks this is basically what we have now, but so far I can't see any advantage over Eclipse!